# R: Plotting fitted values with lme versus lmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, fitting

I am trying to plot fitted values (fitted.sens.early) of the models below as a line over the original values (reading) as points. But I changed from using `lme()` to `lmer()` and the produced graphs don't match up. I cant figure it out myself, so if anyone could help out, that would be greatly appreciated!

An exerpt from my data:

```
        row column plot bed     treatment species  cultivar replicate     time       date calibration reading doy row2 indNr fitted.sens.early fitted.sens.late
    73    1      J   1J   1       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 15:43:34 2022-03-16       Wheat   348.6  75    1     2          419.1706               NA
    74    2      F   2F   1       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 15:46:24 2022-03-16       Wheat   544.3  75    2     2          494.3673               NA
    75   12      R  12R   6       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 15:55:21 2022-03-16       Wheat   587.1  75    1     2          492.8279               NA
    76   21      E  21E  11       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 15:56:26 2022-03-16       Wheat   668.2  75    1     2          537.8255               NA
    77   37      Q  37Q  19 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 16:10:25 2022-03-16       Wheat   376.5  75    1     2          447.3767               NA
    78   38      N  38N  19 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 16:12:37 2022-03-16       Wheat   621.5  75    2     2          513.3009               NA
    79   48      N  48N  24 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 16:20:30 2022-03-16       Wheat   311.8  75    2     2          510.9710               NA
    80   57      F  57F  29 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 16:28:04 2022-03-16       Wheat   577.4  75    1     2          500.3733               NA
    81    1      J   1J   1       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759      BLUE 16:38:55 2022-03-16       Wheat   292.7  75    1     1          318.9814               NA
    82    2      F   2F   1       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759      BLUE 16:49:51 2022-03-16       Wheat   341.2  75    2     1          420.6160               NA
    83   12      R  12R   6       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759      BLUE 16:57:41 2022-03-16       Wheat   354.8  75    1     1          522.2038               NA
    84   21      E  21E  11       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759      BLUE 17:00:01 2022-03-16       Wheat   685.2  75    1     1          530.4388               NA
    85   37      Q  37Q  19 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759      BLUE 17:15:12 2022-03-16       Wheat   307.0  75    1     1          375.7587               NA
    86   38      N  38N  19 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759      BLUE 17:17:52 2022-03-16       Wheat   303.3  75    2     1          495.8043               NA
    87   48      N  48N  24 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759      BLUE 17:27:46 2022-03-16       Wheat   677.8  75    2     1          608.8890               NA
    88   57      F  57F  29 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759      BLUE 17:38:13 2022-03-16       Wheat   552.8  75    1     1          631.1126               NA
    89    1      J   1J   1       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 11:15:54 2022-03-18       Wheat   335.3  77    1     2          411.5344               NA
    90    2      F   2F   1       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 11:19:05 2022-03-18       Wheat   411.9  77    2     2          486.7311               NA
    91   12      R  12R   6       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 11:30:06 2022-03-18       Wheat   465.8  77    1     2          485.1917               NA
    92   21      E  21E  11       Control   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 11:31:56 2022-03-18       Wheat   665.1  77    1     2          530.1893               NA
    93   37      Q  37Q  19 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 11:51:32 2022-03-18       Wheat   514.9  77    1     2          439.1340               NA
    94   38      N  38N  19 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 11:54:44 2022-03-18       Wheat   535.6  77    2     2          505.0581               NA
    95   48      N  48N  24 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 12:02:49 2022-03-18       Wheat   680.5  77    2     2          502.7282               NA
    96   57      F  57F  29 Early drought   Wheat ANSC.2759       RED 12:21:03 2022-03-18       Wheat   540.6  77    1     2          492.1305               NA
etc.
```

I started with the first model,

```
mod.chlo.early.sens <- lme( 
reading ~ treatment*cultivar*doy,
random = ~ 1|plot/replicate,
data = subset(chlo,
date >= start.drought_early & date <= end.drought_early & treatment != "Late drought"),
na.action = na.omit)
```

Then I add the fitted values to my dataframe:

```
chlo$fitted.sens.early[with(chlo, !is.na(reading) & date >= start.drought_early & date <= 
end.drought_early & treatment != "Late drought")] <- fitted(mod.chlo.early.sens, level = 0)
```

And then plot:

```
chlo2<-subset(chlo, cultivar=="ANSC.2759")
ggplot(data = subset(chlo2, date >= start.drought_early & treatment != "Late drought"), aes(x = date,y = reading, color = treatment)) +
          geom_point(size = 0.8, alpha = 0.25)+
          geom_line(data=chlo2[!is.na(chlo2$fitted.sens.early),],
                    aes(y=fitted.sens.early,color=treatment),size = 1.5) +
          facet_wrap(~cultivar, ncol=8)+
          labs(title = "Chlorophyll content", y = expression("Chlorophyll content (  "*mu*mol/m^2*")")),
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -60, hjust = 0), legend.position = "bottom"),
          scale_x_date(breaks = "weeks", date_labels = "%d %b") +
          labs(subtitle = "Period-specific models, early drought",color= "Treatment")+
          scale_colour_manual(values=c("#F8766D","#00BA38"))
```

Which gives me this graph:

[image]

However, I wanted to include another random effect `(1|bed)` in the initial model, which I did not manage to do with `lme()` and so I used `lmer()` instead.

```
mod.chlo.early.sens <- lmer(
reading ~ treatment*cultivar*doy + (1|bed) + (1|plot/replicate), 
data = subset(chlo, 
date >= start.drought_early & date <= end.drought_early & treatment != "Late drought"),
na.action = na.omit)
```

Folowing the exact same subsequent code then produces this graph, where the line is jagged instead of linear:

[image]

Im not sure whether this is simply caused by switching from `lme` to `lmer` or how to fix it.

In any case, using `fitted()` on a `lme` model seems to extract the fitted values differently than when I use `fitted()` on a `lmer` model.

`fitted()` on the `lme` model gives me the same fitted value for each replication (I have 4 replicate plots with two individual plants that were measured inside them)

`fitted()` on the `lmer` model seems to fit each individual plant seperately, as the fitted values differ per replication which causes the jagged line in the plot.

A simple fix might be to include the `(1|bed)` term in the `lme` model, but I can't figure out how to formulate it properly. I keep getting errors.

The more complex fix, I suppose, would be to extract the fitted values properly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `fitted` gives you the fitted values, i.e., subject-level predictions. Consequently, you have multiple y values per date. Change to `predict(mod.chlo.early.sens, re.form = ~0)`. See `help("predict.merMod")`.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot!